# Ember: Uncaught Error: infinite rendering invalidation detected

Tags: ember.js

I am getting below **error** while running one of my **component**:

`Uncaught Error: infinite rendering invalidation detected`

On doing some research, it says this is an issue with Ember but I am not sure, so any thoughts here are appreciated?
I am calling a **service** to return a **promise** and then doing `promise.then(response)` and if there is an **error resolving the promise** I am throwing an error.

Comment: Are there any other errors that show up in the console? Are you using a JavaScript linter? This error usually shows up when there’s a syntax typo. Please paste the code here that causes the error.

Comment: thanks for replying back, Can not paste the code as its an internal project. however I found out the reason. My component was changing some properties in template which led to re-rendering which in turn triggered didReceiveAttrs() function as it invokes again on a re-render. Hence the infinite loop

Comment: You could make a quick ember-twiddle with a very small specific example to help show the issue.

Comment: @sheriffderek hello, apologies for delayed response. The issue has been resolved which was leading to infinite rendering. The cause was the execution of didReceiveAttrs() because of change in the properties on component.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. If that's the case, you should take a few minutes to document it and officially answer this question. : )

Comment: @sheriffderek I will do the same, in-fact I was planning to but got too much occupied in the work. I will post a detailed answer shortly :)